# NSMutableArray converted into UICachedDeviceRGBColor at execution time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.1

Now I'm working on an iPhone project and I'm using instances of the class `NSMutableArray` and suddenly, with no reason, at execution time the `NSMutableArray` converts into a `UICachedDeviceRGBColor` becoming unusable.

I do not know what to do, the same object had been working fine until today.

I got this error:

```
*** -[UICachedDeviceRGBColor count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3e440
```

Comment: Sounds like a memory allocation issue. You should show some code. It's not possible for it to automatically "convert" into some other object. What does your code to initialize the NSMutableArray look like?

Comment: hi Matt!! let me add you the code: 

NSMutableArray *currentIngsGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

currentIngsGroup = (NSMutableArray *)[allIngredientGroups objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"accesing array %d", [currentIngsGroup count]); // here it crashes because detects the currentIngsGroup as UICachedDeviceRGBColor object :(

Comment: If you put your code up in your question, you can take advantage of the auto-formatting and make it a lot more readable.

Comment: And then I scroll down 1 inch and see bbum's comment. Oops.

Answer (score 4):

Next time, stick your code in your question, not the comment.  Here it is nicely formatted:

```
NSMutableArray *currentIngsGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
currentIngsGroup = (NSMutableArray *)[allIngredientGroups objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"accesing array %d", [currentIngsGroup count]);
```

Normally, I would say that the symptom you describe indicates that you are over-releasing something.  The code, though, demonstrates a fundamental lack of understanding of Objective-C.    I would suggest reading the [Introduction to Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) document.

In particular, you are allocating an instance of NSMutableArray in the first line of code.  The second line, though, immediately overwrites the mutable array reference with a reference to whatever object is at index 0 of the `allIngredientGroups` array.

The `(NSMutableArray *)` is totally unnecessary.  It won't force whatever object is in the array to be a mutable array and, since `-objectAtIndex:` returns an `(id)` a cast isn't necessary.

BTW:  The array allocated on the first line is being leaked.  Again, read the introduction to objective-c to understand why.

Comment: Thanks bbum!

Sorry because I didn't place my code in the correct place and I didn't explain that the code lines are was taken from the entire main controller (they are not together). Thanks a lot for your help. I couldn't make the app to work again, thanks God I had a working version at the SVN. Thanks again Alejandra :)

Comment: Happy to help.  Seriously -- go read the intro guide.  It is good stuff!!